# How can I remove Cache-Control metadata in S3 using the CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

In AWS S3, using the CLI, I know how to set Cache-Control headers, like this:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/ s3://mybucket --cache-control 'whatever' --recursive
```

How do I remove the Cache-Control? I want to remove this metadata for every object in a bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only supported way is to replace all of the metadata:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/ s3://mybucket/ --metadata-directive REPLACE --recursive
```

Note that this will replace all of the metadata for the objects, so if you have any other items you wish to maintain, you'll need to recreate them.

Comment: That's not ideal, but thank you.